# How to write a customize xslt reports using with maven in testng

Tags: maven, xslt, testng

Instead of generating reports in default pie charts, i want to customize the reports in own style 
    example : Bar charts , or any other type of representation
    I'm using this code in pom.xml 
    Any one suggest me the way to customize using Xslt in POM.xml

```
 <reporting>
     <plugins>
      <!-- TestNG-xslt related configuration. -->
       <plugin>
       <groupId>org.reportyng</groupId>
       <artifactId>reporty-ng</artifactId>
       <version>1.2</version>
       <configuration>
       <!-- Output directory for the testng xslt report -->
       <outputdir>/target/testng-xslt-report/index.html</outputdir> 
       <sorttestcaselinks>true</sorttestcaselinks>
       <testdetailsfilter>FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS</testdetailsfilter>
       <showruntimetotals>true</showruntimetotals>
       <cssFile>myCustomStyle.css</cssFile>
       </configuration>
       </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of customizing reportNG you may simply develop your own custom html result files.then you may have any structure you want.

All you have to do is to write your own custom reporter class and keep logging the information in it while your test methods are running and after completion simply save and close the file in your project folder.

Although you will be writing more code but you will have more flexibility in its design.